# Replacing the content of a <td> with <tr> id and <tr> index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table structure like this

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr_1">
        <td>Content1</td>
        <td>Content2</td>
        <td>Content3</td>
        <td>Content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2">
        <td>Content5</td>
        <td>Content6</td>
        <td>Content7</td>
        <td>Content8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_1">
        <td>Content11</td>
        <td>Content12</td>
        <td>Content13</td>
        <td>Content14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2">
        <td>Content15</td>
        <td>Content16</td>
        <td>Content17</td>
        <td>Content18</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am passing the row index(2) and `<tr>` id (tr_1) to a js function for replacing the content of 2nd 3 rd td's in that row.
i have a jquery funcion

```
document.getElementById('tr_1').getElementsByTagName("td")[2].innerHTML = '<td>New html</td>';
```

But that this replacing the first `tr` html. How we can replace with id `tr_1` with index 2

Comment: Could you please show your entire function, uncluding the values being passed in

Comment: line of code shown is not jquery, also not a function..

Comment: currently am using javascript. i need a jquery function for this scenario

Comment: where does such a need come from?

Comment: $('#tr_1 td:eq(3)').html('New html')

Comment: your row id's are not unique

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("[id=tr_1]:eq(1) td:eq(1)").html("new html");
```

Note you need to insert the jquery plugin:

http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery .. then this should work..

```
$("#tr_1 td").eq(2).html("<td>New html</td>");
```

here is the link to eq()...
http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: i have two tr with id tr_1 which one will replace?

Comment: You shouldn't have two elements with the same ID in the first place. IDs are required to be unique.

Comment: two elements cannot have same id ....id should always be unique that is why it is called ID... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tr_1 td:eq(1)').html('Replacing Content of td 2');
    $('#tr_1 td:eq(2)').html('Replacing Content of td 3');
});                
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have unique ids. Is is essential for JavaScript that the DOM working with unique ids.

In jQuery you can use this to target the to tr elements with id set to `tr_1`:

```
$("tr[id=tr_1]");
```

To get the second element in these tr's you will need to use [jQuery.fn.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$("tr[id=tr_1]").each(function() {
    $("td", this).eq(1).html("new html");
});
```